# Benefits of reciting Allah's Names?

Tags: dhikr, reciting

I have read on many websites that if one recites a specific name of Allah then he will receive certain benefits, eg, saying Ar Rahman a certain number of times will "remove the defect of forgetfulness" however different websites say different numbers. They also do not cite where they have found this information so i was wondering if there was any specific hadith which clearly stated the benefits of reciting specific names of Allah, eg Ar Rahman, or Al Gaffar etc.

Thank you.

Comment: i am commenting so that perhaps someone will see this question as it has not yet been asnwered